# SwiftUI ScrollView not getting updated?

Tags: swiftui

**Goal**

Get data to display in a `scrollView`

**Expected Result**

[image: data shown in scrollview]

**Actual Result**

[image: a blank view]

**Alternative**

use `List`, but it is not flexible (can't remove separators, can't have multiple columns)

**Code**

```swift
struct Object: Identifiable {
    var id: String
}

struct Test: View {
    @State var array = [Object]()

    var body: some View {
//        return VStack { // uncomment this to see that it works perfectly fine
        return ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ForEach(array) { o in
                Text(o.id)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.array = [Object(id: "1"),Object(id: "2"),Object(id: "3"),Object(id: "4"),Object(id: "5")]
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this on Xcode 11.1, iOS 13.1, Swift 5 and am getting the expected result (although the scroll view is on top rather than center).

Comment: You also don't need the keyword `return`

Comment: interesting, I'm on Xcode 11.2, iOS 13.2, Swift 5

Comment: yeah I had a `print` statement before, hence the `return`

Comment: I'll update to Xcode 11.2 and see if I can reproduce this. It might take awhile but I'll update you on my findings.

Comment: much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Updated to 11.2.1 and I was able to reproduce this. I was able to make the `ScrollView` appear by adding a `frame` modifier to the `ScrollView`

Comment: Did you file a bug (/ Feedback) with Apple? If not please do. You have a nice minimal example for a bug report already.

Comment: I filed FB8101550 with Apple using this code. Thanks for documenting this bug and making a small reproduction case. For posterity: https://github.com/jgale/SwiftUIScrollViewUpdateBug

Answer (score 22):

A not so hacky way to get around this problem is to enclose the ScrollView in an IF statement that checks if the array is empty

```
if !self.array.isEmpty{
     ScrollView(.vertical) {
          ForEach(array) { o in
               Text(o.id)
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found that it works (Xcode 11.2) as expected if state initialised with some value, not empty array. In this case updating works correctly and initial state have no effect.

```
struct TestScrollViewOnAppear: View {
    @State var array = [Object(id: "1")]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ForEach(array) { o in
                Text(o.id)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.array = [Object(id: "1"),Object(id: "2"),Object(id: "3"),Object(id: "4"),Object(id: "5")]
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: that works for the simple case, in my case I have a network call in `onAppear`, so initialising the scrollView with dummy data may be problematic

Comment: correct, but this situation can be handled logically in code, because initial object can be some easy-detected-stub to show conditionally something like 'loading' etc.. for me this was enough... so worth to share.

Answer (score 2):

One hacky workaround I've found is to add an "invisible" `Rectangle` inside the scrollView, with the `width` set to a value greater than the width of the data in the `scrollView`

```swift
struct Object: Identifiable {
    var id: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var array = [Object]()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 0.01)
                ForEach(array) { o in
                    Text(o.id)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.array = [Object(id: "1"),Object(id: "2"),Object(id: "3"),Object(id: "4"),Object(id: "5")]
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The expected behavior occurs on `Xcode 11.1` but doesn't on `Xcode 11.2.1`

I added a `frame` modifier to the `ScrollView` which make the `ScrollView` appear

```
struct Object: Identifiable {
    var id: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var array = [Object]()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ForEach(array) { o in
                Text(o.id)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 40)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.array = [Object(id: "1"),Object(id: "2"),Object(id: "3"),Object(id: "4"),Object(id: "5")]
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not able to get it working on iOS 13.2 on Simulator

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from paulaysabellemedina, I came up with a little helper view that handles things the way I expected.

```
struct ScrollingCollection<Element: Identifiable, Content: View>: View {
    let items: [Element]
    let axis: Axis.Set
    let content: (Element) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if !self.items.isEmpty {
                ScrollView(axis) {
                    if axis == .horizontal {
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(self.items) { item in
                                self.content(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(self.items) { item in
                                self.content(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```