# Api Service Function Can Not Fetch Data At First Trial SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, api, swiftui

This API function of mine called `fetchAuthorArticles` can not fetch JSON data at the first tap. If I close the sheet and tap it once more it does fetch JSON and fills `SelectedAuthorView` screen accordingly. What might be the reason?

```
 class AuthorService: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var authorArticles = AuthorList(author: Author(author_id: 0, articles: 0, newspaper_image: "", author_name: "", author_image: "", newspaper: ""), articles: []) 
    func fetchAuthorArticles(authorID: Int){
        isLoadingPage = true
        if let selectedAuthorUrl = URL(string:"http://author/article/list/\(authorID)/") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            var request = URLRequest(url: selectedAuthorUrl)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                print(data)
                print(response)
                print(error)
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode(AuthorArticleList.self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.authorArticles = results
                                self.isLoadingPage = false
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

AuthorArticleList Model

```
    struct AuthorArticleList:Decodable {
    var author: Author
    var articles: [Articles]
}

struct Author: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int {
        return author_id
    }
    var author_id: Int
    var articles: Int
    var newspaper_image: String
    var author_name: String
    var author_image: String
    var newspaper: String
}

struct Articles: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int {
        return article_id
    }
    var article_id: Int
    var title: String
    var url: String
    var abstract: String
    var article_date: String
    }
```

SelectedAuthorView

```
struct SelectedAuthorView: View {
@Binding var selectedAuthor: AuthorPost
@ObservedObject var service = AuthorService()
var cellNumber: Int = 0
let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0), count: 2)
var body: some View {
 ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(Array(service.authorArticles.articles.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) {i, post in
                            AuthorArticleListItem(articlePost: post, cellNumber: i)
                        }
                        .background(Color(.white))
                        if service.isLoadingPage {
                          ProgressView()
                            .padding()
                            .offset(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4)
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        self.service.fetchAuthorArticles(authorID: selectedAuthor.author_id)
                    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI ScrollView not getting updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830896/swiftui-scrollview-not-getting-updated)